# Is there a name for functions $f$ such that $\{f \le a\}$ is analytic?

Tags: terminology, descriptive-set-theory

Let $X$ be a Polish space and $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ an arbitrary function.  In [The limit inferior of Borel functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1380337/the-limit-inferior-of-borel-functions/1380361#1380361) I showed that a certain function $f$ has the following property:

> For each $a \in \mathbb{R}$, the set $f^{-1}((-\infty, a]) = \{x \in X : f(x) \le a\}$ is [analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_set) in $X$.

**Is there a name for this property of $f$?**

Of course, if the sets $\{x \in X : f(x) \le a\}$ were Borel instead of analytic, then $f$ would simply be a Borel function.  But clearly a function with this property need not be Borel (consider $f = 1- 1_{A}$ where $A$ is analytic but not Borel.

Replacing $\le$ with $<$ in the definition (giving an open half-line instead of closed) would not change anything, since countable unions and intersections of analytic sets are analytic.  But replacing $\le$ with $\ge$ would make a difference, since analytic sets are not necessarily coanalytic.  So I might expect the name to have "upper" or "lower" in it somewhere.

Any elementary properties of this class of functions would also be interesting.  For example, it is easy to see it is closed under countable supremum and infimum, and not closed under negation.

Finally, it could also be interesting to consider replacing $\mathbb{R}$ with some other ordered Polish space (e.g. $\mathbb{Z}$, $2^\omega$, $\omega^\omega$, etc.).

Comment: Doesn't this appear in some form of _grey sets_ in continuous model theory/metric structures? Another comment, do you mean _partially ordered_ Polish? Otherwise, which total order are you considering in the Baire space?

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf: Interesting, I will have to look up "grey sets".  Any suggested references?  Google gives lots of, shall we say, irrelevant hits.  I guess partially ordered Polish spaces could be interesting also but I was thinking of the lexicographic order on $\omega^\omega$.  Not really for any good reason.

Comment: try http://arxiv.org/abs/1405.2859